# ¿Qué significa 'va' en "Nos vemos después, ¿va?"

Tags: definiciones, méxico, saludos

Hoy, por chat, una amiga de México dijo:

> Nos vemos depués, ¿va?

Entiendo "Nos vemos después", ¿pero qué significa "va" en este contexto?

Comment: no le oido por Nicaragua...sera como una abreviacion de ¿Nos vemos depués, vale?

Comment: @cayerdis: Es posible... no sé...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Es una interjección similar a "vale". Se usa para confirmar con el preguntado si está de acuerdo con lo propuesto. En este caso, usando "va" o "vale" provoca que tú confirmes si os véis después o no.

"Va" también puede ser usado como respuesta en lugar de vale:

> —¿Vienes al cine?
>
> —¡Venga, va!

Otro ejemplo con "te hace":

> —Vamos a jugar a fútbol esta tarde, ¿te hace?

"Te hace" busca apelar al interlocutor para que se una a él a jugar.

Comment: Sólo para complementar. Diferentes paises, o incluso regiones dentro de un mismo país, usan diferentes interjecciones para dar el mismo sentido a la frase. Por ejemplo, en México se usa "sale" o "va", es sumamente raro que alguien diga "vale" pero lo he escuchado y jamás he escuchado a alguien decir "te hace".

Comment: @SergioRomero "te hace" creo que es solo en España. "Vale" se usa en Sudamérica, y "dale" en el Cono Sur.

Comment: En la Ciudad de México se usa "vale" mucho.  Tal vez menos que "sale" pero es sumamente ridículo decir que es sumamente raro que alguien la diga.

Answer (score 7):

Podría ser sustituido perfectamente por *OK* o por *vale*.

> Nos vemos despues, ¿OK?
>
> Nos vemos despues, ¿vale?

Realmente no hace falta incluirlo en la oración, pero la pregunta añade énfasis, buscando la aprobación del otro. Es como si el que pregunta esperase un `"sí"` por respuesta al usar `"va"`.

Answer (score 1):

En Cuba no se dice nada de eso (sería "sumamente raro").

Añadimos:

> , ¿si?
>
> , ¿está bien?
>
> , ¿verdad?

o incluso:

> , ¡dale!

Comment: Verdad y Por ejemplo, no tienen nada que ver aquí. Significa algo muy diferente. Verdad? es preguntando, haciendo una confirmación y va? es pregunta pero esperanto una respuesta afirmativa y Por ejemplo, es como un tal vez, pero no veo realción alguna con va.

Answer (score 0):

*¿Va?* es sinónimo de *¿estás de acuerdo?*

Igual le puedes contestar con otro *va* y con ello le estarás confirmando que estás de acuerdo.