# ¿Cómo debo usar "?" al final de una pregunta citada?

Tags: ortografía, puntuación, preguntas

Hace poco pregunté [¿Qué significa 'va' en "Nos vemos después, ¿va?"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2561/12) y el título me hizo pensar en esta:

Cuando estoy citando una pregunta, ¿cómo debo usar el `?` final?

Por ejemplo, ¿cuál es correcto?:

- ¿Dijiste "¿Cómo estás?"
- ¿Dijiste "¿Cómo estás?"?

Y también, supongo es similar con `!`, por ejemplo:

- ¡Dije "¡Vente!"
- ¡Dije "¡Vente!"!

En inglés solo se usa un signo de puntuación, el que está dentro de la cita. Pero en inglés no se usan los `¡` y `¿`, por lo que no parece "desequilibrado" cuando no aparecen dos signos de puntuación al final.

Comment: Wikilengua suggests you could use both, but sometimes only one!  http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Interrogaci%C3%B3n

Answer (score 6):

El correcto es el segundo en los dos casos. Una frase interrogativa/exclamativa debe acabar con el correspondiente signo de interrogación/exclamación, respectivamente.

La confusión puede aparecer por incluir una cita entre comillas, la cual también contiene una oración exclamativa/interrogativa, pero ello no influye para acabar la oración general (la que contiene a la cita) correctamente.

Answer (score 2):

Como menciona BrianA en [un comentario](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/2562/c%c3%b3mo-debo-usar-al-final-de-una-pregunta-citada#comment4190_2562), [Wikilengua](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Interrogaci%C3%B3n#Repetici.C3.B3n_de_los_signos_de_interrogaci.C3.B3n) dice esto (citando la *Ortografía y ortotipografía del español actual*):

> ### 5 Repetición de los signos de interrogación
>
> ...
>
> - Enunciado interrogativo que aparece dentro de otro:
>
> > ¿Has visto la película *¿Arde París?*?
>
> Según José Martínez de Sousa<sup>[1]</sup>, en un caso como el del ejemplo, dado que debe colocarse el título de la película en cursiva, podrían mantenerse ambos signos. Sin embargo, en otros casos se tiende a pensar que uno de los signos de cierre sobraría, pues el restante aseguraría la entonación interrogativa. No solo eso, además, hay que tener en cuenta que la presencia de varios signos de interrogación no aumenta la inflexión interrogativa. Por otro lado, en aquellos casos se podría recurrir a una distribución de los elementos de una forma diferente.

1. [*Ortografía y ortotipografía del español actual*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=c7rjAAAAMAAJ&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=Arde+Par%C3%ADs), José Martínez de Sousa (p.389)