# ¿Puede haber signos de interrogación dentro de otros signos de interrogación?

Tags: ortografía, puntuación

Leyendo esta mañana una pregunta en meta de SOes: [¿Por qué "¿Puede alguien ayudarme?” no es realmente una pregunta?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2845/por-qu%C3%A9-puede-alguien-ayudarme-no-es-realmente-una-pregunta)  me ha sorprendido ver una pregunta dentro de otra y me ha surgido la duda de si eso está bien hecho.

En principio no veo nada de malo al ser una pregunta que habla de otra pregunta y además va entrecomillada pero me ha parecido extraño a la vista y al leerla no sabía muy bien como se debía entonar.

El [DPD](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=bH8aKhoE1D6eF5Wp4C) no dice nada de este tema,al menos en la entrada ***interrogación*** y tampoco he encontrado solución en la *Nueva gramática de la lengua española*.

¿Es correcto el uso de interrogaciones dentro de interrogaciones? ¿En caso afirmativo hay límites para la anidación?

Comment: Relacionadas: [Preguntas dentro de preguntas](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17125/1674) y [¿Cómo debo usar “?” al final de una pregunta citada?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2562/1674).

Comment: @fedorqui Vaya, no había visto esas preguntas. Me temo que la mía es un duplicado entonces.

Answer (score 3):

No creo que haya limitación.  Lo cierto es que no es muy frecuente, y en el caso que pones, las marcas van dentro de las comillas, por lo que no debe haber problema alguno.

Interesantemente, en mi comentario sobre *zas* en otra pregunta, la cita de Mafalda usa dos marcas exclamatorias y no me parece problema, es como para enfatizar más una parte de la oración ya exclamada:

> ¡Es horrible! ¡La gente gente estudia, termina su carrera y… ¡zas! se va al extranjero!

Así podríamos imaginar alguna situación en que sería aconsejable, o incluso necesario, usar dos pares de marcas interrogativas:

> ¿Cuándo vas a casar con ¿Marcos era su nombre??  Pues él.

La doble marca al final puede parece raro pero tampoco tanto, y es como lo haríamos si hubiese una exclamatoria: ¿……¡…!?